# execute bash script via getJSON and pass argument to it

Tags: jquery, linux, bash, web, client-server

I'm able to execute bash script on server side linux via getJSON method

```
$.getJSON("settings/test_test.sh", function( data ) {
    var items = [];
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        if(key=="retval"){
            if(val=="ok"){
                return;
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
    });
    console.log("Command Video: Error execuite script.");
    return;
});
```

But i want to type an argument to it! I found some problems when i tried to implement this. Is there any possibilities to decide this problem? 
My bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
"1")
        sed -i -e 's/abc/xyz/g' /var/www-utils/file.txt
        ;;
"2" | "3")
        sed -i -e 's/xyz/abc/g' /var/www-utils/file.txt
        ;;
*)
        sed -i -e 's/abc/acb/g' /var/www-utils/file.txt
        ;;
esac

[
        {
                echo '"retval": "ok"'
        }
]
```

Everything works as expected when I execute script on server-machine. 
But if I'm trying to do same problem is GET `http://192.168.10.1/settings/test_test.sh%201 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Do you really think that allowing public access to a bash script on your server is a good idea?

Comment: Hello Rory McCrossan! Yes, that's my goal, to allow public access to a server-side scripts. Device I'm working with it's switch with yocto-linux kernel. I want to allow change settings of it